# undefined method `model_name' for #<Hash:0x007efcfb0c19e0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I using `gem 'firebase'` and getting data from firebase. I can `create,show` data but problem with `update action` . here is my code  `user.rb` file

```
require 'firebase'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   FIREBASE = Firebase::Client.new("url" ,"secret")
   def self.all
     response = FIREBASE.get('users')
     response.body.present? ? response.body : {}
   end

   def self.find(id)
     FIREBASE.get("/users/#{id}").body
   end

   def self.update(id, data)
     response = FIREBASE.update("/users/#{id}", data)
     return response.success?
   end
end
```

and users_controller.rb file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :json

  def edit
    @user = User.find("#{params[:id]}")
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    User.update("#{@user[0]}", user_params)
    respond_with @user
  end
 private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

and edit.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

here is my error logs:

```
Started GET "/users/-KOKEM82melqy/edit" for 180.211.159.218 at 2016-08-04 12:19:58 +0000
Cannot render console from 180.211.159.218! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"-KOKEM82melqy3"}
  Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for #<Hash:0x007efcfb7c6ab0>):
    1: <h1>Editing user</h1>
    2: <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    3:     <div class="field">
    4:       <%= f.label :name %><br>
    5:       <%= f.text_field :name %>
  app/views/users/edit.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_users_edit_html_erb__2046577153275023374_69812507750700'
```

i tried a lot of times but noting work. any suggestion ? 
if u need more information about this, please let me know. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is the line number of the error? Maybe the line where appear `user_params`?

Comment: i didn't add user_params in question, i'll add it shortly

Comment: Yes, in update method

Comment: hey, i added error logs

Comment: Why do you use `ActiveRecord::Base` if it is not a model over database table?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently

```
def self.find(id)
  FIREBASE.get("/users/#{id}").body
end
```

returns a `Hash`.

So you either need to convert it to `User` class instance or you can't use `form_for` helper.